# Add parameters to an npx tsx cli script

Tags: typescript, tsx

I'm triggering a .ts file to run with `npx tsx script.ts`

How would I pass parameters to the command?

Example:

`npx tsx script.ts --name=Bill`

And access those parameters in the file:

Example scripts.ts:

`console.log(name, 'should show Bill')`

Is that possible with tsx? If not what is a system where I could pass in named parameters and execute a ts file directly?

Comment: How is `name` defined in your `script.ts` file? You're basically after some sort of `process.argv` parser like [Commander.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander)